# cannot read property query of undefined

Tags: node.js, heroku-postgres

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3myJ.png)[My file database/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOV8S.png)

I´m trying execute a query on my heroku database, but any request to the database causes this error.

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');

const pool = 
    new Pool({connectionString : Process.env.DATABASE_URL, ssl : true});

module.exports = {
    query : function(text, values, ret_cb, err_cb){
        pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
            client.query(text, values).then(ret_cb).catch(err_cb);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It's better to embed your images, rather than link to the images.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `err` value in your callback from `pool.connect(...)`, you're probably getting a connection error.

The simplest debugging is to log out the values of `err` and `client`:

```
pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
    console.log('err=', err);
    console.log('client=', client);

    client.query(text, values).then(ret_cb).catch(err_cb);
});
```

For interactive debugging it might be work looking at [Debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27).